# Can't log into GUI login screen with user who has ssh and sudo access after setting password

Tags: server, xorg, login, password

I can log into a box via ssh using an ssh key, passwordless.

I have set my password using `sudo passwd myusername` and I get the success message `passwd: password updated successfully`.

When I try to log into the GUI console using that password I get two beeps (sounds like a failure tone I think) and it just goes back to the list of users.

Are there some tricks that might be disallowing my user from logging on via the console? How would I even debug the issue? I don't see anything obvious in `dmesg`.

Comment: "console" meaning a GUI login screen here I assume (since you mention a "list of users")?

Comment: Yes, thanks, I've updated the verbiage to be more clear.

Comment: Can you log in at one of the CLI virtual terminals (Ctrl-Alt-F2 thru Ctrl-Alt-F6). Does your user have a valid, writable home directory? Is there a `~/.Xauthority` file, and if so what are its ownership and permissions?

Comment: @steeldriver thanks! It was the permissions of ~/.Xauthority (and a few other files) that were set to root, I didn't know to look at that. I changed ownership and can now log in. If you'll post that as the answer I'll gladly accept it. And thanks for the help.